# How to instrument Spring Boot 3.x with Spring Cloud Stream 4.x producers and consumers to correlate tracing information in loggers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, micrometer

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3 I've had to update the tracing/correlation configuration to switch from Spring Cloud Sleuth to the new Micrometer Tracing library.

At this point I can see traceId/spanId information in the logs, which is correctly transmited to other services using HTTP calls with an automatically instrumented `WebClient`.

However, it seems that Spring Cloud Streams Kafka producers and consumers aren't being instrumented.

Here's an example of the producer:

```
logger.debug("Sending message to kafka queue {}", message)
streamBridge.send(bindingName, message)
```

Logs with the traceId,spanId:

```
[producer,638b36642e4fe0b203b7f32b746b22de,03b7f32b746b22de] 52233 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] i.s.m.p.p.ProjectTaskEventProducer       : Sending message to kafka queue GenericMessage [xxx]
[producer,638b36642e4fe0b203b7f32b746b22de,03b7f32b746b22de] 52233 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Creating binder: kafka
```

On the consumer side I have this simple KStream:

```
    @Bean
    fun processEvent() =
        Function<KStream<EventKey, EventValue>, KStream<EventKey, EventValue?>> { events ->
            events.process(
                ProcessorSupplier {
                    Processor<EventKey, EventValue, EventKey, EventValue> {
                        logger.info("{}", it.headers())
                    }
                }
            )
        }
```

Logs

```
[consumer,,] 52544 --- [-StreamThread-1] ventKStreamConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0 : RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = target-protocol, value = [107, 97, 102, 107, 97]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 116, 97, 114, 103, 101, 116, 45, 112, 114, 111, 116, 111, 99, 111, 108, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false)
```

As you can see only two headers were transmited (`target-protocol` and `spring_json_header_types`), with the `b3` header missing. Thus, MDC logs aren't being setup either.

The [Micrometer documentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#_instrumentation_of_messaging_communication) is very sparse regarding messaging instrumentation so it's not clear how to do it in the context of Spring Cloud Stream.

- Shouldn't `StreamBridge`, like `WebClient`, be automatically instrumented?
- Same thing on the consumer side.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've added a `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer` as indicated, enabling observation for the underlying `KafkaTemplate`.

```
@Configuration
class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun kafkaProducerObservationCustomizer () : ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer<KafkaProducerMessageHandler<EventKey, EventValue>> {
        return ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer<KafkaProducerMessageHandler<EventKey, EventValue>> {
                handler, destinationName ->
            handler.kafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

When `StreamBridge` is invoked the execution ends up in the customizer that sets the observationEnabled property to true:

[image]

However, the consumer still gets only two headers:

[image]

If you compare the `ObservationRegistry` that correlates the logs for the HTTP calls:

[image]

It is different from the one inside de KafkaTemplate:

[image]

The problem seems to be here in `KafkaTemplate`:

[image]

The observationRegistry is initialized during the application startup, when the `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer` hasn't been invoked yet. Thus, the value of observationEnabled will always be false, not executing the if block and defaulting to the NOOP registry:

```
private ObservationRegistry observationRegistry = ObservationRegistry.NOOP;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've tried this workaround

```
@Configuration
class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun kafkaProducerObservationCustomizer (applicationContext: ApplicationContext, observationRegistry: ObservationRegistry) : ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer<KafkaProducerMessageHandler<ClientProjectId, ProjectTaskEvent>> {
        return ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer<KafkaProducerMessageHandler<ClientProjectId, ProjectTaskEvent>> {
                handler, destinationName ->
            handler.kafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true)
            handler.kafkaTemplate.setApplicationContext(applicationContext)
            handler.kafkaTemplate.afterSingletonsInstantiated()
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work though. It seems to mess with the configuration of the producer, overriding its values. In my case it looks for a local Kafka cluster instead of the configured one:

```
2022-12-05T17:36:06.815+01:00  INFO [metrics-ingestor,,] 8056 --- [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Node -1 disconnected.
2022-12-05T17:36:06.816+01:00  WARN [metrics-ingestor,,] 8056 --- [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying `KafkaTemplate` does not enable micrometer tracing by default, you have to set `observationEnabled` to `true`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#observation

With Spring Cloud Stream, you can achieve this with a `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer`  `@Bean`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/4.0.0-M3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_advanced_producer_configuration

The handler type is `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`; so use `handler.getKafkaTemplate().set...` to alter its properties.

Comment: Hi Gary, there's a problem with the customizer, even though it configures `observationEnabled(true)`, the KafkaTemplate still references a Noop ObservationRegistry. I've detailed the problem in the UPDATE of the question.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, the binder doesn't use a bean for the `KafkaTemplate`, it creates one for each binding. Furthermore, the binder doesn't inject the application context, so it won't find the registry anyway. Try injecting the context and calling `afterSingletonsInstantiated()` after setting the property. Please open a bug against Spring Cloud Stream. The binder should inject the context and call aSI() after calling the customizer. Since there is a context in your debugger - you must be inspecting a different template.

Comment: Ok, I'll open the issue. There's one thing left, what about the consumer (KStream) side? How can we instrument that bit so that MDC logging is properly set based on the received `traceparent` header?

Comment: I don't know about that - Spring is not involved with KStreams runtime processing, only setting it up.  Not sure if anything can be done about that; I suggest you mention it in the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2576

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2577